# The algebraic possibilities of the (topological) procedure of the compactification of a space

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, compactness

If $X$ is locally compact $K$-vector space, then $X\cup \{\infty\}$ is via the Alexandroff-compactification a compact space.
But this purely topological procedure tells me nothing about the algebraic relationship of $\infty$ to rest of the $x\in X$.    What can be said about this relationship ?
 What kind of definitions for $x+\infty$ and $\lambda\cdot \infty$ are meaningful ? And for which $x\in X$ and $\lambda \in K$ ?
What can be said about the algebraic structure of $X\cup \{\infty\}$ ?

Comment: You could compactify $X$ by embedding it in a projective space, where you have some "algebraic" structure. I don't think there'll be much algebraic structure on the one point compactification when $X$ has dimension $\geq 2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the one-point compactification $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$ of $\mathbb{C}$, i.e. $\overline{\mathbb{C}} = \mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$, you don't even get that $(\overline{\mathbb{C}},+)$ is a group because $\infty$ has no additive inverse.

So very little of the algebraic structure of a topological space transferrs to its one-point compactification.